# SQL Like condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, sql-like

I have 2 sql tables
first table called processed

```
relatedorders (type in nvarchar)
132,112,144,155
116,113
11,44,15,16
```

and second table called orders and looks like

```
orderid (type int)
132
112
155
116
```

I want to select orderid from orders table where the orderid exists in relatedorders in processed table

I tried somthing like

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT relatedorders 
             from processed 
             where orders.orderid  like %relatedorders %)
```

but it doesn't seem to work as it should, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should be using a join table not storing the values as comma-separated text in a single column.  Even if it worked, you'll have problems with comma-separated values since, for example, you'd have not match `1116` but should match `116,...`, `...,116,...`, and `...,116`.

Comment: @tvanfosson so no simple way to match other than a seperate table? and about performance will a seperate table perform faster?

Comment: I think it would be faster in all cases, but with appropriate indexes it would be *much* faster as you won't incur a table scan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to model this is with a one-to-many relationship through a *join* table.  Add another table, perhaps called `ProcessedRelatedOrders` containing the id of an order and the id of a related order, one row per relationship.  You will likely want.  Use both columns as the primary key.  The index on the primary key should allow fast look up for a join with the processed order.